# Process.arguments in createprocess?

Tags: c#, createprocess

The following works just fine in process.start situation.

```
private string Path()
        {
            RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wizet\\");
            RegistryKey Location = Key.OpenSubKey("MapleStory");
            return Location.GetValue("ExecPath").ToString();
        }

public bool Launch()
        {
            maplestory = new ProcessStartInfo();
            maplestory.FileName = Path() + @"\MapleStory.exe";
            maplestory.Arguments = "WebStart";

            MapleStory = Process.Start(maplestory);
}
```

Where would I now place the '.Arguments' if I were to use CreateProcess and where would I place CREATE_SUSPENDED as well?

```
CreateProcess(AppName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second argument you can put command line options. And in the sixth you can put creation options like CREATE_SUSPENDED.

`CreateProcess(AppName, "WebStart", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);`

For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public uint dwProcessId;
    public uint dwThreadId;
}

public struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public uint cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public uint dwX;
    public uint dwY;
    public uint dwXSize;
    public uint dwYSize;
    public uint dwXCountChars;
    public uint dwYCountChars;
    public uint dwFillAttribute;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public short wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int length;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CreateProcess
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();

        CreateProcess("MapleStory.exe", "WebStart", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CreateProcess(AppName, "WebStart", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);
```