# C# Start Excel using Process Not Working in Firefox Native Messaging but works in Chrome

Tags: c#, firefox-addon, chrome-native-messaging

Here is my host app in c#.

**Edited**: I've changed my sample host app code to simple code.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\sample.xls");
    }
}
```

When my program runs using Firefox extension, the excel doesn't open. And if I use Chrome extension, the excel is opening without any problem.

Here is my **Firefox** extension settings:
**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "ExcelPrint",
  "description" : "ExcelPrint",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions" :[
    "activeTab", "nativeMessaging", "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
      "scripts": [
          "background.js"
      ]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Firefox: **sample.excelprint.json**

```
{
  "name": "sample.excelprint",
  "description": "ExcelPrint API Host",
  "path": "ExcelPrint.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_extensions": [
    "3042a0d1d72c86e7952c552c6984bbea99bc5f0e@temporary-addon"
  ]
}
```

And here is my **Chrome** extension settings: **manifest.json same as firefox**

Chrome: **sample.excelprint.json**

```
{
  "name": "sample.excelprint",
  "description": "ExcelPrint API Host",
  "path": "ExcelPrint.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://ncdpaccgfgdcifdjlncninlegabfgkgl/"
  ]
}
```

Need help how can I open the excel using firefox extension.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#app_persistance):

> When a native messaging connection is closed, Firefox kills the
> subprocesses if they do not break away. On Windows, the browser puts
> the native application's process into a Job object and kills the job.
> Suppose the native application launches other processes and wants them
> to remain open after the native application is killed. In that case,
> the native application must use CreateProcess, instead of
> ShellExecute, to launch the additional process with the
> CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB flag.

Basically, in Firefox (unlike Chrome and Edge) the second process gets killed after the native process finishes. So, we need to use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) function with [CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags#flags) flag.
CreateProcess can't execute files, just applications, but we can make use of cmd.exe application to open the excel file.
Thanks to [Process.arguments in createprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308836/process-arguments-in-createprocess) , I have come up with the following solution:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FirefoxNativeMessagingLauncher
{
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public uint dwProcessId;
        public uint dwThreadId;
    }

    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public uint cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public uint dwX;
        public uint dwY;
        public uint dwXSize;
        public uint dwYSize;
        public uint dwXCountChars;
        public uint dwYCountChars;
        public uint dwFillAttribute;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const uint CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB = 0x01000000;
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
            CreateProcess(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", @"/c c:\sample.xls", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);
        }
    }
}
```